# Hdfs replication factor 1 override default behaviour

Tags: hdfs, hadoop2

Is there a way to override default behaviour for the first replica block on  hdfs?

What I'd like to do is to assure that the copy of a block is on a different datanode when I set dfs.replication=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement your own Block Placement Policy. But this is really not hard at all. Your class should extend `org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockPlacementPolicy`. What you want to implement is very simple, so just copy the [default block placement policy class](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/trunk/hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/server/blockmanagement/BlockPlacementPolicyDefault.java) and modify it so that it behaves as desired.

Answer (score 1):

**Override Replication and Block Size using CLI:**

***Here I am setting the Replication factor 2 for this file:***

```
~]$ hadoop fs -D dfs.replication=2 -put -f /home/cloudera/cricketers /user/cloudera/Dec_17_2017/Dec_18
```

***Here I am setting the Block size = 128 MB for this file:***

```
 ~]$ hadoop fs -D dfs.block.size=134217728  -put -f /home/cloudera/cricketers /user/cloudera/Dec_17_2017/Dec_18
```

***Here setting both, Block size = 128 MB and Replication = 2 for this file:***

```
~]$ hadoop fs -D dfs.block.size=134217728  -D dfs.replication=2 -put -f /home/cloudera/cricketers /user/cloudera/Dec_17_2017/Dec_18
```